# Store formatting information in an array then apply it to a range

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a script that will automatically format a selection based on the formatting of a table in another sheet. The idea is that a user can define a table style for header, rowOdd and rowEven in the Formats sheet, then easily apply it to a selected table using the script.

I've managed to get it working, but only by applying one type of formatting (background colour).

I based my code for reading the code into an array on [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) article.

As you will hopefully see from my code below, I am only able to read one formatting property into my array.

What I would like to do is read all formatting properties into the array, then apply them to the range in one go. I'm new to this so sorry if my code is a mess!

```
function formatTable() {

  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange(); //range to apply formatting to
  var arr = new Array(activeRange.getNumRows());
  var tableStyleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Formats"); //location of source styles
  var tableColours = {
    header: tableStyleSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1).getBackground(),
    rowEven: tableStyleSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1).getBackground(),
    rowOdd: tableStyleSheet.getRange(3, 1, 1).getBackground()
  } 

  for (var x = 0; x < activeRange.getNumRows(); x++) {
    arr[x]  = new Array(activeRange.getNumColumns());
    for (var y = 0; y < activeRange.getNumColumns(); y++) {
      x == 0 ? arr[x][y] = tableColours.header : 
      x % 2 < 1 ? arr[x][y] = tableColours.rowOdd : arr[x][y] = tableColours.rowEven;
      Logger.log(arr);
    }

  }
  activeRange.setBackgrounds(arr);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong but based from the list of methods given in [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), feature to save or store formatting details currently do not exist yet.

However, you may want to try using the following:

- `copyFormatToRange(gridId, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)` or `copyFormatToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)` wherein it copies the formatting of the range to the given location.
- `moveTo(target)` wherein it cuts and paste (both format and values) from this range to the target range.

Comment: I think you're right on the lack of feature to store all formatting. I wanted to avoid using copyFormatToRange because it would require selecting multiple ranges in both source and target since the ranges are not the same size and layout. My understanding is that selecting the ranges carries a performance penalty vs applying the array to a range (probably a very small penalty in my example!)

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that you can get all of the different formatting elements for a range straight into an array?

E.g.

```
var backgrounds = sheet.getRange("A1:D50").getBackgrounds();
var fonts = sheet.getRange("A1:D50").getFontFamilies();
var fontcolors = sheet.getRange("A1:D50").getFontColors();
```

etc.

However, there's no way to get all of the formatting in one call unfortunately, so you have to handle each element separately. Then you can apply all of the formats in one go:

```
targetRng.setFontColors(fontcolors);
targetRng.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
```

and so on.

Comment: Isn't this what I'm using already? (sorry if I've misunderstood you). I can't directly apply the array from the source range to the target range because the sizes are different i.e. `tableStyleSheet` has one row for each style,  but the target range might be hundreds of rows. My code includes a for loop that builds an array the same size and layout as the target range.